# Failed to add the child at index 0

Tags: c#, uwp, swipe, uwp-xaml

So I've started learning UWP programming and to learn how to use the Swipe methods I've used this link: [Swipe Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/swipe)
But after following their steps I've started receiving the following error: *Failed to add the child at index 0.*  and the following lines of code we're highlighted

```
       <SwipeItems x:Key="RevealOptions" Mode="Reveal">
            <SwipeItem Text="Touch it" IconSource="{StaticResource TouchIcon}"/>
            <SwipeItem Text="Eat it" IconSource="{StaticResource EatIcon}"/>
        </SwipeItems>
        <SwipeItems x:Key="ExecuteBuying" Mode="Execute">
            <SwipeItem Text="Buy it" IconSource="{StaticResource BuyIcon}"/>
        </SwipeItems>
```

Here's the complete code:

```
 <Page.Resources>
        <SymbolIconSource x:Key="TouchIcon" Symbol="View"/>
        <SymbolIconSource x:Key="EatIcon" Symbol="Emoji"/>
        <SymbolIconSource x:Key="BuyIcon" Symbol="Like"/>

        <SwipeItems x:Key="RevealOptions" Mode="Reveal">
            <SwipeItem Text="Touch it" IconSource="{StaticResource TouchIcon}"/>
            <SwipeItem Text="Eat it" IconSource="{StaticResource EatIcon}"/>
        </SwipeItems>
        <SwipeItems x:Key="ExecuteBuying" Mode="Execute">
            <SwipeItem Text="Buy it" IconSource="{StaticResource BuyIcon}"/>
        </SwipeItems>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <SwipeControl Name="MySwipeContainer"
                      LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                      RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
            <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ListViewItem Content="Apple" FontSize="36"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Banana" FontSize="36"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Grape" FontSize="36"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Lemon" FontSize="36"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Melone" FontSize="36"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Watermelon" FontSize="36"/>
            </ListView>
        </SwipeControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I had the same trouble (`Failed to add the child at index 0`) and I have noticed that my solution configuration was set to `ARM`. I guess this happened after a troublesome build of the application packages (for deploying it on other computers). Now, I wonder why ARM gives this error. UWP is not that universal afterall?

Answer (score 0):

From the document, it puts the SwipeControl in the DataTemplate, so, you need to use the SwipeControl wrap the listviewitem instead of ListView. Your code would like the following:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <SwipeControl 
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
                <ListViewItem Content="Apple" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl 
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
                <ListViewItem Content="Banana" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl 
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
                <ListViewItem Content="Grape" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl 
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
                <ListViewItem Content="Lemon" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl 
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
            <ListViewItem Content="Melone" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
            <SwipeControl
                  LeftItems="{StaticResource RevealOptions}"
                  RightItems="{StaticResource ExecuteBuying}">
                <ListViewItem Content="Watermelon" FontSize="36"/>
            </SwipeControl>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but even after using your code I'm receiving the following error: _The resource "ExecuteBuying" has an incompatible type._ and  _The resource "RevealOptions" has an incompatible type._

Comment: Could you build and debug your app in visual studio? I also face this issue because some classes are introduced from 16299(e.g, SymbolIconSource). But if you run your app on 16299 system, it will not affect your app. Your app still will be able to run successfully.

Comment: This `Failed to add the child at index 0` is still an issue. And even when I run the app, what I get is a mangled view with the swipe buttons permanently sticking on top of the item when I hover. Definitely not what it is supposed to happen... No wonder developers don't write apps for UWP (without even going to the terrible design of the whole framework).